# Skip ansible progress task if dependent step is skipped

Tags: ansible

I would like to skip ansible progress task below if the dependent task is skipped ? How would I achieve it ?

```
- name: long running shell
  shell:
    cmd: '/opt/apps/long_running_script.sh'
  async: 1000
  poll: 0
  when:
    verify.rc != 0
  register: check_status

- name: Check on long running step
  async_status:
    jid: "{{ check_status.ansible_job_id }}"
  register: job_result
  until: job_result.finished
  retries: 90
  delay: 10
```

I tried using `when: check_status is finished` but seeing the error when the first task is skipped.

Answer (score 3):

When a task is skipped, the resultant variable will have a property name `skipped` with value `true` so you should be able to write logic like below.

```yaml
when: check_status.skipped | default(false)
```

The default will be needed because for the regular flow (not skipped) skipped property will not be available in `check_status`.

or,

```yaml
when: check_status.skipped is defined and check_status.skipped
```

even simpler as @β.εηοιτ.βε commented,

```yaml
when: check_status is skipped
```

Comment: but now, seeing this error
```The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'dict object' has no attribute 'ansible_job_id'```

Comment: Basically, you will need to define default in all the places `check_status` is used and may be skipped. Like, `check_status.ansible_job_id | default('undefined')`. Change the implementation as suits the requirement.

Comment: `when: check_status is skipped` is even easier https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_conditionals.html#the-when-statement

Comment: Absolutely @β.εηοιτ.βε and thanks. I probably have just gone with the flow.